# Can I annotate @EntityListener on interfaces?

Tags: jpa, interface, entitylisteners

I'm designing database and entities. I need to define shared lifecycle actions for some entities.

Can I annotate `@EntityListeners` on interfaces so that entities implementing the interface affects?

```
@EntityListeners({StorageObjectOwnerListener.class})
public interface StorageObjectOwner {
}

public class StorageOwnerOwnerListener {

    @PreRemove
    private void onPreRemove(final Object object) {
    }
}
```

Now any entity implements get affected.

```
public class MyEntity implements StorageObjectOwner {
    // will StorageObjectOwnerListener take action?
}
```

Comment: @NeilStockton I wouldn't post this kind of question if I won't care about any implementation specific behaviour. What a classic comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried that with JPA 2.1. Sadly, it only seems to work with entities. So if your idea is using an interface, or even a superclass that is not an entity, it won't work.

[Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) says:

> When annotations are used, one or more entity listener classes are
>   denoted using the EntityListeners annotation on the entity class or
>   mapped superclass.

You could however use a default listener (set in XML configuration). That way it would trigger on any object being removed. You'd have to filter them with `object instanceof StorageObjectOwner`.